# First Person out of 130?

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that the amount of time it takes for a student to finish a Math 425 midterm is a random
variable with uniform distribution between 40 and 60 minutes. What is
the probability that the first person to be done with the test will leave after at most 41 minutes?

My thinking was the probability that one person leaves after at most 41 minutes is .05 since it is a uniform distribution.

Therefore out of 130 people, the probability that at least one person finishes in at most 41 minutes out of 130 is 1-(.95^130). Following from this, picking that one person is 1/130 so divide the previous calculation by 130
I feel I'm close and I want that last step.

This was previously asked but the answer was unlike anything we've learned so I thought if i added some of my thoughts, someone could get me to the finish line.

Answer (score 0):

Let's denote the event you are interested in by A. Then (assuming the times taken by the students are independent)

$$P(A^{c}) = (\frac{19}{20})^{130}.$$

So

$$P(A) = 1 - (\frac{19}{20})^{130} = 0.998... $$

**NB** Implicit in your question is that there are 130 students. You didn't actually state this in the question. My calculation above assumes this.

Comment: are you saying A is the event that at least one finishes in at most 41 minutes. I understand this and had it. Using that, how can i get the probability that out of the 130 students, the first one picked has at most 41 minutes

Comment: Yes, that's what I am saying. The two events are complementary so the sum of their probabilities is 1.

Comment: sorry if i'm being redudant. So simply, the probability of the first pick out of 130 students finishing in at most 41 minutes is the same as the probability of at least one finishing in at most 41 minutes ( aka your second calculation with the .998)

Comment: No: P(at least one finishes before 41 minutes) = 1 - P(everyone takes more than 41 minutes to finish)